# how to get requred field from file on linux?

Tags: linux, shell, unix

I have one file which contains three fields separated by two spaces. I need to get only third field from file. File content is as in following example:

```
kuldeep  Mirat  Shakti
balaji  salunke  pune
.
.
.
```

How can I get the third field?

Comment: For/With what do you want that field? Are we talking about an bash-script for print-out? Generating an new file with only third field? Reading and parsing the file in an program you develop?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To get the 3rd field, assuming you don't have any "embedded spaces", just

```
awk '{print $3}' file
```

awk by default sets whitespaces as field delimiters. So even if you have 2 spaces or more, the 3rd field is always $3.

However, if you want to be specific, then specify a Field delimiter

```
awk -F"  " '{print $3}' file
```

If you have other choices, a Ruby one

```
ruby -F"  " -ane 'print $F[2]' file
ruby -ane 'print $F[2]' file
```

Update: If you need to get all fields after 3rd,

```
awk -F"  " '{$1=$2=$3=""}1' OFS="  " file # add a pipe to  `sed 's/^[ \t]*//'` if desired

ruby -F"  " -ane  'puts $F[3..-1].join("  ")' file
```

Comment: thanks for ans. but i need all fields from third field. e.g as per my example i need to get all fields after "shakti"

Comment: @balaji, that's not what your question says.  Please edit your question to give your actual requirements.

Answer (score 2):

Use `awk`:

```
awk -F'  ' '{print $3}' file
```

This also works if fields may contain embedded spaces.

Comment: I believe it must be: 
awk '{print $3}' filename

Comment: Yes I did, and it works for me. What does it do on your system?

Comment: which shell are you using? it prints nothing... but when I use awk '{print $3}' filename it works

Comment: @sharpner, which OS are you on? Which version of `awk`?

Comment: GNU bash, Version 4.2.8(2)-release (i686-pc-linux-gnu)
arch linux
but I found the problem, I got three spaces in the textfile after the first word

Comment: awk '{print $3}' filename is still the best solution in my opinion since the number of spaces don't matter

Comment: @sharpner: 1. the shell version has nothing to do with this, 2. the OP says he has double space-delimited fields so obviously it may matter. `awk '{print $3}'` doesn't work when fields contain spaces.

Answer (score 0):

To get the third field of each line, pipe through awk, e.g

```
cat filename | awk '{print $3}'
```

If you just want to get the third field of the first line, use head, too:

```
cat filename | head -n 1 | awk '{print $3}'
```

Comment: No need for `cat` in either command. This also doesn't work if fields contain spaces.

Comment: There's no need for either cat or head: awk 'NR==1 {print $3}' filename

Answer (score 0):

Given @balaji's comment to @kurani's answer:

```
perl -pe 's/^.*?  .*?  //' filename
awk -F'  ' '{for(i=3; i<NF; i++) {printf("%s%s",$i,FS)}; print $NF}' filename
```

Answer (score -2):

less filename | cut -d" " -f 3

Comment: `less` just incurs overhead here. `cut` only works with single-char delimiters, so this doesn't work when a field contains an embedded space.

Comment: This is definitely a new twist on UUOC.